# Why is this expectation calculation wrong?

Tags: probability

Let

$E(X|A)=2+E(X)$

$E(X|B)=3+E(X)$

$E(X)=0.5E(X|A)+0.3E(X|B)$

Now to find $E(X^2)$ I did

$E(X^2|A)=4+E(X^2)$

$E(X^2|B)=9+E(X^2)$

$E(X^2)=0.5E(X^2|A)+0.3E(X^2|B)$

What did I do wrong here?

Edit.

For a recursive conditional expectation like this,

$E(X^2|A)=E[(2+X)^2]$

$E(X^2|B)=E[(3+X)^2]$

$E(X^2)=0.5[4+4E(X)+E(X^2)]+0.3[9+6E(X)+E(X^2)]$

where $E(X)=9.5$

Comment: How did you get the second set of equations?? You can't just replace $X$ with $X^2$, and square some of the constants.

Comment: @CalvinLin The first set is given, the second set I thought you would just square the X and sum it up like E(X)?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. $E(X) = \int x \, dx$, $E(X) = \int x^2 \, dx$. Also, it is not clear what you want to do. Are you trying to find $E[X^2]$? Is $A\cup B$ the entire probability space?

Comment: You can calculate that $E[X] = 9.5$ from the first 3 equations. However, you can't find much about $E[X^2]$ otherwise.

Comment: @calvinlin It's a discrete probability. The probability sapce is A,B,C with $E(X|C)=0$. From what I understand is $E(X^2)=X_1^2P(A)+X_2^2P(B)+0P(C)$

Comment: The discrete version is that $E[X] = \sum x f(x), E[X^2] = \sum x^2 f(x) $. Also, you should mention that $E[X|C]= 0$. Please state your problem properly, we are not mind readers.

Comment: @calvinlin X is a count that goes up until you choose C which it would end, and you would keep going if you choose A and B. $X|C=0$ $X|A=2+X$ $X|B=3+X$.

Comment: YOu should state the problem properly and completely. No one is able to read your mind, nor know what you are trying to talk about.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, as the question is not stated. I'm merely trying to show what information can be gleamed from the question. I'd delete this answer later.

---

Judging from your comments, the probability space is $\{ A, B, C \}$. Hence,

$\begin{align}
E[X] & = P(X=X(A) ) \times E[X|A] + P(X=X(B)) \times E[X|B] + P(X=X(C)) \times E[X|C] \\
& = P(X=X(A)) \times X(A) + P(X=X(B)) \times X(B) + P(X=X(C)) \times X(C) \\
\end{align}$

**However, we do not know what $P(X=X(A))$ is.**

From the first 3 equations, we get that

$$E[X] = 0.5 (2+E[X]) + 0.3 (3 + E[X]) \Rightarrow E[X] = 9.5, E[X|A] = 11.5, E[X|B]=12.5 $$